# My profile page just broke after adding several code blocks

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page

After adding a few code blocks, the about me section on my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16936415/martes-berkeley?tab=profile) just overflowed the page horizontally.

[image: My broken profile page]

There are supposed to be scrollbars on the code blocks and not on the page itself.

---

### Device Details

I don't know whether other people can see this bug or not. Here are some details to reproduce the bug.

- Browser: Microsoft Edge 94
- Operating System: Windows 11

Comment: Can see it in chrome as well.

Comment: Sigh, here we go again. Repro in FF 93.0 on Linux Mint. This is a regression of one of many bugs (take your pick - has historically happened on profiles, questions/answers, 10k tools, revision history, etc.) where code block scroll bars are disabled, meaning sufficiently vertically long code blocks break the container size. This is sadly not contained to profiles; the 10k tools have also broken, but in a weirder way. (The scrollbar is applied in the wrong place). Questions and revision histories are good at least

Comment: oh, no, it is a well-known issue reported several times. Will find a couple of related links shortly. What wretched reason they decided not to do proper text wrapping for, I have no idea.

Comment: @OlegValter text wrapping doesn't always make sense for code. How they manage to repeatedly break scrollbars, however, is beyond me. You'd think they'd have tests for it by now

Comment: @Zoe I know :) That said... many of us provided alternatives to this overflow. The scrollbars issue is very tightly related to the inability to fix the source issue...

Comment: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYqHZ.png) of the issue fixed with a one-line change in CSS.

Comment: Didn't they recently intentionally break profiles because they were making it "responsive"? Oh, [they reverted that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/194720) never mind :).

Comment: For what it's worth, repro on MacOS with Brave (i.e. essentially Chromium)

Comment: [It's fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371111/818993)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. The problem was due to a way that `pre` tags interact with flexibly sized containers (a css `grid` column in this case). Since I probably can't explain it well enough, [here is an article](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/) that does.

From the linked article:

> I can’t promise I’m explaining this 100% accurately, but the way I understand it, the minimum width of a grid column is auto. [...]
> And since auto is entirely based on content, we can say it is “indefinitely” sized, its dimensions flex. If we were to put an explicit width on the column, like 50% or 400px, then we would say it is “definitely” sized.
> To apply our fix, we need to make sure that there is the column has a definite minimum width instead of auto.

Despite the somewhat unintuitive cause, the fix is actually pretty simple.

As for why we don't do text wrapping on code blocks, it's precisely *because* they are code blocks. This is generally a personal opinion (like tabs vs spaces), but the stance we are taking is that applying text wrapping to code can cause unnecessary confusion in regards to things such as line numbers and literal whitespace (which is important in certain languages like Python).